# Cookie header exists in GET request but not POST request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, express

**Background**

I have an application using NextJS as frontend, NestJS as backend.

When I send api request from FE to BE, the flow looks like this

```
NextJS -> Axios -> NestJS
```

In NextJS client component

```
axios.post('/transactions', {...payload});
```

axios.ts

```
let instance = axios.create(defaultOptions);

// Set the AUTH token for any request
instance.interceptors.request.use(async function (config) {
  const accessToken = await getCookie("accessToken");
  config.headers.Cookie = `accessToken=${accessToken}`;
  return config;
});
...
```

main.ts in NestJS

```
  app.enableCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
  });
```

**Problem**

I just hosted my backend in GCP(the domain is HTTPS).
However, when I send POST request from my frontend(`localhost:3000`) to the hosted backend,
the `Cookie` header aren't in the request header, but it exists in GET request.

If I send the request to my local server(`localhost:3001`), the POST request works perfectly with `Cookie` header set up.

What is the possible reason for this issue?

Comment: I don't use either of these frameworks, but is `origin` from `app.enableCors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000' })` being updated to your production domain when you deploy? If not, that's likely your issue. I'm not sure why `GET` and not `POST` would work in this situation, but I'm sure someone else who knows the CORS spec off the top of the dome has the answer.

Comment: @sheng I am trying to access the production api in my local frontend application, so I didn't update it to my production domain

Comment: I'm almost certain you cannot set request cookies manually like that

Comment: Do your defaultOptions include withCredentials?